Is a 3 blade propeller at same RPM and diameter quieter than 2 blade?
READ: Knowing that a 3 blade will be quieter for the same thrust compared to a 2 blade as mentioned in 3 vs 2 prop post and multiple other articles(because the size and speed on the 3 blade can be reduced), however my question is, if both are doing the same RPM and the same diameter(hence generating different thrusts), will the 3 blade still be quieter?
A link to a video with a test with a sound level meter would be awesome(I couldn't find any online). Can't believe no one has a video of this somewhere.

No.  Each blade sees more wake from its predecessor, because its predecessor is closer.  So each blade sees more turbulence and thus makes more noise than the equivalent 2-blade, not less.  See e.g. section 3 of JPL TR 32-7462.
That paper cites NACA TN 2968, A review of aerodynamic noise from propellers, rotors, and lift fans, which plots noise vs. blade count (e.g., fig. 2), showing that fewer blades are noisier -- but for the same horsepower (and thus different diameters), unlike this question (same diameter, thus different horsepower).

Still, for the same thrust the lift coefficient will be lower for the four blade prop. This means all pressure variations should be lower, too. Lower overspeeds also means lower tip Mach peaks.

+1 for the JPL paper. It says on page 6: "Hubbard, in Ref. 8, constructed, from solutions to this equation, plots which show that the noise level increases with absorbed power, increased diameter, fewer blades, and especially with increased tip speed".

Most 3 blade conversions of 2 blade engines, very popular on the DeHavilland Beaver, seem to be quieter only because the blades can be shorter to absorb the torque and don't become transonic.

I'm confused, if the noise level increases the fewer blades it has then that means that the 2 blades will be noisier than 3. Is this answer wrong then?

No contradiction.  That paper says that fewer blades are noisier when power stays constant.  I've edited to clarify.

So in short, if the blade length is the same, 3 blades is noisier than 2 at any given RPM, but 3 blades produce more thrust, so in practice the 3 blade prop is quieter because the blades can be shorter and run at a lower RPM in any given flight regime.  Is that about right?

Honestly I find this study confused and overcomplicated for my question and in the wording and so old, I can't believe there isn't a video out there someone has done this test....this is not like a million dollar study to do by NASA, its just put two props and see which one makes more noise at same RPM with a sound level meter.  My question is very simple.

@DarthPseudonym, right.  Design in practice doesn't add or remove blades while keeping rpm and diameter constant.  It also varies those.

At the same rpm and diameter, more blades aren't quieter, they're louder.
My other answer shows that, as blades are added, each blade becomes louder.  But it's even simpler to show that, as they're added, the propeller as a unit becomes louder.

The noise comes from the air disturbed by the propeller.

This disturbance is overwhelmingly from each blade.

So, at fixed rpm and diameter, more blades means more disturbance, which means more noise.  QED.


What's hard about recording a video demonstration of this is simply finding two otherwise identical props with different blade counts.  An inexpensive way would be to buy two 4-blade model airplane props and from one of those cut off two opposing blades to make a 2-blade.  Or find a hub with room for either one or two 2-blade props, to create a 4-blade.
Finding a matching 2- and 3-blade is even harder.  One vendor has a pretty close match, but even there some dimensions slightly differ.
